# How to create two additional columns in a results set to act as axis for a heatmap

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, query

I have a set of results from a WSUS report that consists of computername and the status level of patching on that computer.

I have been asked to display this as a heatmap e.g each computer is a single cell with a color assigned depending on the patch status (e.g. failed, waiting for reboot, downloaded etc) and to do this I need some columns to use as axis. Heatmaps needs 3 columns (x,y and heat) I only have the heat at the moment.

I can do this with cursors iterating over each row incrementing the counters for two columns and inserting the row plus these two values into a temp table and then return that but it is not efficient.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Ultimately I am after

```
Computer Name | Heat | X | Y
Comp1         | 4    | 1 | 1
Comp2         | 4    | 1 | 2
Comp3         | 4    | 2 | 1
Comp4         | 4    | 2 | 2
```

Where X & Y are the generated columns (i.e. not in the data returned from the query)

I am using SQL Server Express 2014 for dev but the production target will probably be 2012 or 2014 full version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*<sub>Answer originally left by the question author in a comment</sub>*

Final solution was:

```
SELECT 
    ..., 
    (((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))) -1 ) / @cnt) + 1 AS X,
    (((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))) -1 ) % @cnt) + 1 AS X
```